# How to make the log of fabric as daily rolling?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am running the fabric on the machines instead of docker containers, each service per host, now my question is how can I make the log as daily rolling? Otherwise the single log will be larger and larger, it does not make sense. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot currently configure any type of log rotation for the peer or orderer nodes.  Assuming you are running on Linux, you might want to have a look at [logrotate](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/logrotate.8.html)

Comment: Yes I am running on the Linux server, thanks for your answer , appreciate it very much!